# 2 windows opening on JavaScript link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I am having an issue when I click on my JavaScript link it is opening on 2 tabs instead of one

```
Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${_book_now}", "click", function(sym, e) {
         window.open("http://www.etihad.com", "_blank");
```

Can anyone see why this would happen.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `return false` before the end of the function. This will prevent default behaviour (at least with jQuery).

Edit
What about:
`e.preventDefault();`?

See http://forums.adobe.com/message/4412987

Comment: Where exactly would I put the return false, sorry not very familiar with JS